# How to use Sqlite Database in browser for offline usage

Tags: sqlite, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I have developed one application in ionic for offline mode. I have used sqlite database to store the data. Now i want to create a browser build. But sqlite  is not supported  in browser.  Is there any way to use sqlite in browser?

Or else is there any database which works same as sqlite for browser.(*kindly do not suggest websql database and pouchdb*)

i am using pouchdb for now, but there is lots of redevelopment because queries in pouchdb and sqlite are very different

Answer (score 0):

As of this moment there is no way of using SQLite with ionic in the browser. Did you maybe find a solution to your own problem?

For anyone reading this that wants to purely use SQLite in their app (instead of localstorage) you can use a livereload build on a test device and easily debug and test your code this way. Just connect dev tools and see all the console messages.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).